# Best practice for updating table cells based on notifications

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view of custom cells representing individual uploads and each cell has a progress indicator in it and a success/error icon.  I want to update the cells as progress is updated and indicate if it was a success/failure. I do this by having my upload controllers broadcast NSNotifications for progress/success/failure.

Is it better to:

**A)** have each cell have a NSNotification listener for these notifications and update the cell view

**OR**

**B)** have the table view controller have a NSNotification listener listen for these notifications and then set the values for each cell by getting cells with cellForRowAtIndexPath.

I guess it comes down to **A** is easier to implement but I'm wondering if there is a performance penalty to have so many listeners listening to those notifications and doing a 'IF this notification is about me...'.  As opposed to **B** which only has one listener, and can be generalized to any multi vs single listener design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set up Key-Value Observation (KVO) for your table view to handle row updates, then use it (with a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass) to update the cells with information from your objects. See [Using KVO for Table Updates](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/11/using-kvo-for-table-updates.html) for an example of using KVO for section/row updates.

Comment: +1 Just remember that cells are reused, so if the cell itself is observing the data (rather than the TableViewController doing it), then make sure to remove it as an observer from its old data before adding it as an observer to its new data.

Comment: Yep! And just to be clear, you’d do that by subclassing `UITableViewCell` and overriding `-prepareForReuse`. In that method, stop observing the object.